# Remember my jquery cookie values in new window

Tags: jquery, cookies

Not sure how to do this, I'm setting a jQuery cookie on a link on a page which then opens a new window. So on window 1 - cookie value is set to `XXX`. Window 2 is a page where user can update this cookie value to anything i.e. `XYX`, `YYY` etc.

So I want to be able to update the cookie value in window 1 with what the user has changed in window 2.

At the moment I have 2 windows one with `$.mycookie(test, xxx)` and `$.mycookie(test, yyy)`. If user closes window 2 his change is not updated in window 1.

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly make the cookie available for all paths on your domain, make sure the path is set:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { path: '/' });
```

To limit it to a specific path instead:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { path: '/foo' });
```

If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain . If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain . The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

Comment: Yes i already set my path to '/', but by changing my cookie value in window 2 does not update the value of my cookie in window 1

Comment: @user1010701 I don't seem to understand why your cookie is not updated. Probably the cookie gets expired. Can you try: $.cookie('example', 'value', { expires: 14, path: '/' });? This sets expiration to +14 days.

Comment: I need to refresh my parent window when i close the child window so have used window.opener.location.reload(); to refresh my cookie , which works

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you need to refresh the opener window.

Window-1 via javascript opens Window-2 (the popup) and this popup needs to have a function called when unload event is fired for when it closes and/or when a button/link is clicked that refreshes the parent window. Cookie changes that happen in the way you are doing them can only be active after a refresh.

Simple Window-2 Example:

```
<script>
function whatever() {
    $.cookie("test", $('input[name=cookievalue]').val());
    if (window.opener != null) {
        window.opener.location.reload();
        window.close();
    }
}

$('button[name=clicker"]').bind('click', function(){
    whatever();
});

/* optionall you can also do an unload event, 
 * but you should probably check if you ran whatever() more then 
 * once and not run it a second time.
 */
$(window).unload(function(){ 
    whatever();
});
</script>

<input type="text" value="" name="cookievalue">
<button name="clicker">Change Cookie and close</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, very useful i'm going to try this and will let you know how i got on.